# Page Scroll Up when mouse click on anywhere in body

Tags: javascript, jquery

My home page having code like below. I have called a Javascript function `onpage load`. In that blink function is doing blinking the Input text, in the particular time interval.

```
<body onload="blink()";/>
 <form>
  <input autocomplete="off" onkeydown="if (this.value=='xxx xxx xxx ?') this.value='';StopBlinking();" type="text" class="search_input" name="searchword" id="searchword" onKeyup="request(event);" value="xxx xxx xxx ?" onclick="if (this.value=='xxx xxx xxx ?') this.value='';StopBlinking();" onfocus="if (this.value=='xxx xxx xxx ?') this.value='';StopBlinking();" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='xxx xxx xxx ?';"/>
  <div class="clicked-area">
     ....Did something.....
  </div>
  </form>

</body>

<script>
function blink() {
   document.getElementById("searchword").focus();

     if(document.getElementById("searchword").value == "XXX XXX XXX XXX")
     {
       document.getElementById("searchword").value = "";
     } else if( document.getElementById("searchword").value == "" ){
        document.getElementById("searchword").value = "XXX XXX XXX XXX";
     }

     timer = setTimeout("blink()", 500);
}

function StopBlinking()
{
  clearTimeout(timer);
}

</script>
```

In this page when have clicked anywhere on the `div` `"clicked-area"` unexpectedly my page is scrolling to top.

But when I remove timeout method from the script `"timer = setTimeout("blink()", 500);",` then it's not happening. Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why `blink()` in double quote? `setTimeout("blink()", 500);` . And, which browsers have that problem?

Comment: Hai Vothaison. All browsers have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

why do you want to remove the blink function at first? if your main goal is just to move the page on top when clicked-area is click you can just move the function on clicked-area when click

```
<div class="clicked-area" onclick="blink()">



function blink() {
document.getElementById("searchword").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is normal. When an input gets focused using script, the whole page needs to scroll to the position of the input.

You click anywhere outside the input, you make it lose focus. Then `blink()` runs again and the input gets "re-focused". The whole page then scrolls up (since the input is on the top).

If you try putting a bunch of br tags between the input and the clicked-area div so that page is longer, you will see the effect more obviously.

Does the input need to be focused all the time?

Comment: Thanks vothaison. You are right, But we need to focus the input box at all time.